# Showing default selected value in editable dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've an editable dropdownlist in the cshtml page as follows.
I need to show "PT2" as the default selected value in the dropdownlist instead of "Select".

```
<input id="ProductType" list="ProductTypeList" name="product-type-list" placeholder="Select">
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.ProductType, new SelectList(model.ProductTypeList,"")  
    )
```

Model:

```
public class Product
{

    public string ProductType {get; set;}
    public List<string> ProductTypeList {get; set;}
}
Example values in ProductTypeList : "PT1", "PT2", "PT3"
```

Wondering if this is possible in the above code? Any thoughts or pointers please??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="ProductType" list="ProductTypeList" name="ProductType" placeholder="@Model.ProductType">

<datalist id="ProductTypeList">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductTypeList)
    {
        @if (item == Model.ProductType)
        {
            <option value="@item" selected>@item</option>
           
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@item" >@item</option>
        }

       
    }
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you Abolfazl. That did not work. This is an "editable" dropdownlist. I believe above solution would work for the regular dropdownlist.

Comment: I edited my code(This is an "editable" dropdownlist and default value is PT2 and instead of "Select" use "PT2"),I hope this is code help you,@Mitu